# Why are the outputs of the comparators in a 555 timer inverted?

Tags: 555, flipflop

I'm confused as to why the outputs of the comparators in a 555 timer are inverted (and inverted again on the NOT Q output of the flip-flop).

Would it not have been easier to leave the comparator outputs unmodified and just connect the output pin to the Q output of the flip-flop?

Comment: You need to show the internal schematic that you refer to. There are several on the web and clarity is needed.

Comment: A picture is worth a 1000 words.  It really is hard to visualize what you are looking at since there are various diagrams on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to the circuit shown, for example, in the [ST NE555 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000479.pdf). That document shows the below functional diagram.

[image]

To start with, the flip-flop (FF) is just a part of the 555's transistor circuit and not a separate block, as the diagram suggests. That can be seen on the schematic within the datasheet. The FF circuit's `/Q` node is just as accessible as its `Q` node.

`/Q` is the correct polarity for driving the `DISCHARGE` pin's output BJT, rather than `Q`.  The 555 designers used `/Q` to drive the (relatively) high-current inverting push-pull output stage for the `OUT` pin.

So the block diagram is trying to represent how the IC actually works and not just show the simplest equivalent for the 555's function.